# app.config being ignored?

Tags: c#, app-config, webservice-client

I have read several posts where users were having this same issue. When compiled, the .exe is unable to load any resources from app.config. This is occurring even when the app.config is copied to the output directory.

Specifically, I'm having an issue with a web service client being unable to determine the proper endpoint configuration, even if I statically compile it in like this:

```
this.ws = new MyServicePortTypeClient("MyServicePort", "http://mysite.com/customer_portal/ws.php");
```

The exception thrown states "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyWebService.MyServicePortType' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

I'm at a loss so any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Here's the MyService.exe.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://mysite.com/customer_portal/ws.php"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding"
                contract="MyWebService.MyServicePortType" name="MyServicePort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If the same exception is being thrown whether you set the config in app.config or not, it seems to me that app.config is not involved in your actual issue.

Comment: If that's the case, what would it be? Further details that may be of use are that it's a Windows service application. It works fine when I debug it through Visual Studio, but after I install it with installutil, it gives me this error.

Comment: Can you **show us** the app.config you're using? This error is most likely due to a malformed WCF config in that file. Just the `<system.serviceModel>` section - thanks!

Comment: I just added it to the original post above, taking into consideration what Shadow Wizard posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out with the help from the information provided by everyone.

The issue is that installutil.exe is trying to use its own config, instead of the one created by the service. In this case, It's trying to load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0...\InstallUtil.config.

Now that I've figured that out, I can work with it and get it to work correctly.

Thanks, y'all!

Comment: well, you never mentioned using installutil.exe - glad you got it solve anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

EXE is taking the settings from *FileName.exe.config*, not from App.config

The *FileName.exe.config* should be auto generated when compiling the code, and placed alongside the EXE itself.

Check the folder where you have the EXE.. do you see *FileName.exe.config* in there?

(Posted as answer due to length and formatting)

Comment: I checked and there is indeed a FileName.exe.config, which I've added to the original post. It's being ignored just the same though.

Comment: WCF service usually has .svc extension so I'm not sure what's going on. I doubt you can write WCF service with PHP. Maybe the client is throwing error because the PHP code does not return valid response.

Comment: Please read the post starting with "Well, I figured it out..." in this thread. The PHP endpoint is not the issue.